# Moodle ошибка кодировки

Tags: кодировка, moodle

Cтолкнулся с ошибкой кодирования при выборе курса или других различных разделов. Рядом на этом же сервере стоит сайт на такой же версии платформы и работает корректно. Выдает такую ошибку, подскажите как исправить?

Чистил весь кеш, не помогло.

```
Debug info: 32767
Error code: codingerror
Stack trace:
    line 7226 of /lib/moodlelib.php: coding_exception thrown
    line 76 of /lib/classes/output/mustache_string_helper.php: call to get_string()
    line 494 of /var/www/moodledata/localcache/mustache/1572514822/classic/__Mustache_63a202a85b3a4b9550951faec4c65fef.php: call to core\output\mustache_string_helper->str()
    line 74 of /var/www/moodledata/localcache/mustache/1572514822/classic/__Mustache_63a202a85b3a4b9550951faec4c65fef.php: call to __Mustache_63a202a85b3a4b9550951faec4c65fef->section207568e320c11be848642cb4f4209702()
    line 67 of /lib/mustache/src/Mustache/Template.php: call to __Mustache_63a202a85b3a4b9550951faec4c65fef->renderInternal()
    line 191 of /lib/outputrenderers.php: call to Mustache_Template->render()
    line 2093 of /lib/outputrenderers.php: call to renderer_base->render_from_template()
    line 226 of /lib/outputrenderers.php: call to core_renderer->render_single_select()
    line 478 of /lib/outputrenderers.php: call to renderer_base->render()
    line 1628 of /course/renderer.php: call to plugin_renderer_base->render()
    line 66 of /course/index.php: call to core_course_renderer->course_category()
```